# gitignore file is not working properly

Tags: git, github

Extract of ".gitignore" file

```
/Api/bin/log4net.dll
/Web/bin/log4net.dll
/Api/bin/System.Web.Http.dll
/Api/bin/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
/packages
```

When I try to commit :

[image]

Question : How to get rid of these repackage files when I try to commit (.gitignore is in root )?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Firstly commit any outstanding code changes into your local master.

Type below commands on **Git Bash.**

**Step 2 :** Move into your local repository directory (The root where your .gitignore file resides).

```
cd "D:\Freelance Work\My Mvc Project"
```

**Step 3 :**

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

This removes any changed files from the index(staging area).

**Step 4 :**

```
git add .
```

**Step 5 :** Commit it.

```
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have those files committed before you add the lines in gitignore.

If that's the case, you have to remove them from tracking.

If you are using windows, cd to the path of your local git. For example if your git repo folder is in c:\project\projectA, you should type

```
cd /c/project/projectA
```

Then you have to untrack those file one by one by the below command:

```
git rm Api/bin/log4net.dll
```

After you remove them all, you have to commit.

Answer (score -2):

If the files were already checked in, then you need to remove them before git will start ignoring them. See if the files are listed when you run `git ls-files`. If they are, then see the SO answer that has been suggested as a [possible duplicate of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Where should I type above command ? cmd or else ? Can you give more info ?

Comment: On the command prompt in Linux.  In Windows, I think you need to install git bash.

Comment: Yes.I do have git bash.Can you tell me how to set the initial path for my repo on local folder on it before run the above command ?

Comment: That's a question for a Windows user.  If you already know the path, then `cd PATH_TO_REPO` (replacing PATH_TO_REPO with the path).